# Extract multipart rar, deleting parts as they are extracted

Tags: windows, compression, rar

I have a multipart rar of 80GB unpacked. I have 5GB of free space, and every part of the rar archive is 2GB.

What I'm looking for is to extract one part, delete it, extract the next, and so on, as to use at most 5 more GB in the extraction process and not exhaust all my disk space.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I tried searching on the net and on superuser :p I have no idea what software I could use. 7zip seems to not delete anything ever, and winrar seems to only delete if *everything* was successful, so all files at once. If I can't find a solution I will have to write it myself in python, which is bad since I'm almost certainly going to ruin the archive and have to redownload it a bunch of times :)

Comment: You can make a small archive and run your scripts on that with configurable size limits before you go full scale. Also, as far as I know, unrar allows for single-file extraction without the need to unpack the whole archive, so you can search the list (use l switch) to find the file(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:**

- this script **WILL** delete the parts done extracting regardless of the end result, so if the process stops for a missing or corrupted part, you would not be able to start over

---

- Open notepad and paste the following code and save it as **_unrar.vbs** in the same folder with your rar files.
- Set **UnRAR_Full_Path**, **First_Part** and **Target_Folder**, make sure to keep the quotes.

The Script:

```vbs
UnRAR_Full_Path = "c:\program files\winrar\unrar.exe"
First_Part = "YourArchiveName.part001.rar"
Target_Folder = "ExtractedFiles\"

mf_command = AddQuotes(UnRAR_Full_Path) & " x " & AddQuotes(First_Part) & " " & AddQuotes(Target_Folder)
mf_LZerosSplit = Split(First_Part, ".")
mf_LZerosPart = Mid(mf_LZerosSplit(UBound(mf_LZerosSplit)-1), 5)
If UBound(mf_LZerosSplit) > 3 Then
    WScript.Echo ("Too Lazy to deal with names the contains dots, only 2 are allowed. one before 'part' and one before 'rar'")
    WScript.Quit 1
End If
mf_LZ_UnderTen = ""
mf_LZ_UnderHundred = ""
mf_LZ_UnderThousand = ""

If Len(mf_LZerosPart) = 2 Then
    mf_LZ_UnderTen = "0"

ElseIf Len(mf_LZerosPart) = 3 Then
    mf_LZ_UnderTen = "00"
    mf_LZ_UnderHundred = "0"

ElseIf Len(mf_LZerosPart) = 4 Then
    mf_LZ_UnderTen = "000"
    mf_LZ_UnderHundred = "00"
    mf_LZ_UnderThousand = "0"
End If 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.Exec(mf_command)
Set objStdOut = objWshScriptExec.StdOut

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine

    'WScript.Echo (strLine)

        If InStr(strLine,"Extracting from") Then
            mf_filename = Mid(strLine, 17)
            mf_partnameSplit = Split(mf_filename, ".")
            mf_partname = mf_partnameSplit(1)
            mf_partnumber = Mid(mf_partname , 5)
            If mf_partnumber > 1 Then
                mf_numtodel = mf_partnumber-1
                mf_LeadingZeros = ""
                If mf_numtodel < 10 Then
                    mf_LeadingZeros = mf_LZ_UnderTen
                ElseIf mf_numtodel < 100  Then
                    mf_LeadingZeros = mf_LZ_UnderHundred
                ElseIf mf_numtodel < 1000  Then
                    mf_LeadingZeros = mf_LZ_UnderThousand
                End If
                mf_filetodel = mf_partnameSplit(0) & ".part" & mf_LeadingZeros & mf_numtodel & ".rar"

                'WScript.Echo ("NOW DELETING: " & mf_filetodel)

                Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                obj.DeleteFile(mf_filetodel)
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(strLine,"All OK") Then
            WScript.Echo ("looks like All Ok, Delete the Last part and Have a nice day :)")
        End If
Wend

Function AddQuotes(strInput)
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & strInput & Chr(34)
End Function
```

**Option one:** Silent

run the **_unrar.vbs** file by double clicking it

**Option two:** Recommended

remove the **'** from the start of

```vbs
'WScript.Echo (strLine)

'WScript.Echo ("Deleting: " & mf_filetodel)
```

open cmd, direct to your folder and type **"cscript _unrar.vbs"**

- using **WScript.Echo** without **cscript** will popup too many annoying message boxes

---

this script works by reading the Stdout of UnRAR.exe.

### EDIT

Improved the script to automatically work with any name structure and with any number of parts up to 9999 parts. and to work with legacy archives that does not contain leading zeros.

Comment: wow, thanks. I'll run this as soon as the download finishes completely. I do understand the consequences of the script, but in my case, if I do goof up, I can redownload the archive from the server as many times as I want, so no worries there.

Comment: Actually, could you change it to work for <100 archives? My idea was to delete the two lines starting at elseif and change ".part00" to ".part0" but if possible I'd like to avoid redownloading everything because I tried changing a program in a language I don't understand :)

Comment: I added what you'll need to change for Parts < 100.

Comment: Thanks a ton, still waiting for the download to finish. I will let you know if this works!

Comment: No problem, I tested the script and it should work just perfect :) , good luck

Comment: m fran, I improved the script. you don't have to worry about anything now. just add your values and you're good.

Comment: If you have password proteced archive modifiy this line:

Password = "urPassword"
mf_command = AddQuotes(UnRAR_Full_Path) & " -p" & AddQuotes(Password) & " x " & AddQuotes(First_Part) & " " & AddQuotes(Target_Folder)

Comment: You need an english version of winrar or something like that, because otherwise the "Extracting from" is never printed.
Also the partition character was missing for me in the delete file name:
"mf_filetodel = "J:\" & mf_partnameSplit(0) & ".part" & mf_LeadingZeros & mf_numtodel & ".rar"

Comment: @murphy1312 about the language, I've always assumed that RAR.exe releases in English only but I think you're right since I never checked. so this should be taken into account. 
about the missing partition character, the script assumes that it is in the same directory as .rar files so I uses relative paths but yes you can edit the path as you like if needed