# Extract multipart rar with password, deleting parts as they are extracted

Tags: windows, compression, rar

how can I use this on rar with password? I know the password is

https://superuser.com/a/1031807/1136215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line 5 with:

```
mf_command = AddQuotes(UnRAR_Full_Path) & " x -pPASSWORD_HERE " & AddQuotes(First_Part) & " " & AddQuotes(Target_Folder)
```

Obviously put in the password instead of PASSWORD_HERE.